# In German, how to say "We would never hear the end of it"?

Tags: expression

We were talking about ... My girlfriend whipped up a mousse-like cold dessert with some fresh fruits, but the thick slices of apple inside turned out a bit too frozen to eat as is. And here I wanted to jokingly say something along the lines of:

> If somebody cracked a tooth on one of those frozen solid apples, **we would never hear the end of it!**

---

In German, the first phrasing that came to mind was:

> Wenn sich jemand an einem dieser stocksteif gefrorenen Äpfel einen Zahn ausbeißt, **dürfen wir uns noch in zehn Jahren die Beschwerden anhören!**
>
> ≈ We might as well still be hearing some complaint or other in ten years' time.

... for want of a more faithful-to-the-original phrasing. How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in German?

Answer (score 5):

Some possibilities to express the given idea are:

> Beißt sich jemand an einem Apfel einen Zahn aus, werden wir das anschließend
>
> - [noch] lange
> - ewig
> - eine Ewigkeit
>
> zu hören bekommen!

Comment: "bis in alle Ewigkeit" is also an option.

Comment: Noch eine Variante:  "werden wir das bis ans Ende aller Tage zu hören bekommen".

Comment: Früher auch vermehrt "bis zum St. Nimmerleinstag" - womöglich v.a. in katholischen Gegenden, wo man für jeden Zweck einen eigenen Heiligen hatte.

Answer (score 2):

More solutions:

Wenn sich jemand an einem dieser steinhart gefrorenen Äpfel einen Zahn ausbeißt...

> ... hängt uns das bis in alle Ewigkeit an.
>
> ... trägt man uns das bis zum Sanktnimmerleinstag nach.
>
> ... kriegen wir das nie mehr los.
>
> ... kriegen wir das unser Lebtag nicht mehr los.
>
> ... sind wir auf immer die Schuldigen / Deppen.